# How to index into array with variable in batch?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I'm trying to process input arguments to a batch file, and I need to tie some paired arguments together before I call an executable at the end. I'm placing all the arguments into an array so I can process them, but I can't figure out the batch equivalent of "get the value of the next entry in the array". The following is what I'm trying:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
set "Batchmode="
set "RelativePaths="
set "DbFile="
set "TemplateFile="
set "LuaFile="
set "LogFile="
set i=0
:TOP
IF (%1) == () GOTO END
    set args[!i!]=%1
    set /A i+=1
SHIFT
GOTO TOP
:END

set argsLength=!i!
echo argsLength: !argsLength!
for /l %%n in (0,1,!argsLength!) do ( 
    set /A nextIndex = %%n + 1
    echo n: %%n, arg: !args[%%n]!, nextIndex: !nextIndex!, nextIndexArg: !args[!nextIndex!]!
    if !args[%%n]! equ -batchMode set Batchmode=-batchMode
    if !args[%%n]! equ -relativePaths set RelativePaths=-relativePaths
    if !args[%%n]! equ -dbFile set DbFile=-dbFile !args[!nextIndex!]!
    if !args[%%n]! equ -templateFile set TemplateFile=-templateFile !args[!nextIndex!]!
    if !args[%%n]! equ -luaFile set LuaFile=-luaFile !args[!nextIndex!]!
    if !args[%%n]! equ -logFile set LogFile=-logFile !args[!nextIndex!]!
)

if !argsLength! geq 2 (
// do some input verification stuff here
)

start /wait "" "MyExeFileHere.exe" !Batchmode! !RelativePaths! !DbFile! !TemplateFile! !LuaFile! !LogFile!
```

I'm running the batch file with the following command:

<batchFilePathHere.bat> -batchMode -relativePaths -dbFile <dbFilePathHere.db>

The output I'm getting from the echo line inside the for loop is as follows:

n: 0, arg: -batchMode, nextIndex: 1, nextIndexArg: nextIndex

n: 1, arg: -relativePaths, nextIndex: 2, nextIndexArg: nextIndex

n: 2, arg: -dbFile, nextIndex: 3, nextIndexArg: nextIndex

n: 3, arg: myDbFilePathHere.db, nextIndex: 4, nextIndexArg: nextIndex

n: 4, arg: , nextIndex: 5, nextIndexArg: nextIndex

I can't figure out why !nextIndex! evaluates to the value of nextIndex when it's on its own, but not when it's placed inside an array accessor. I've also tried using !args[nextIndex]! but all those values come up empty, I'm assuming because it's using the memory address of nextIndex instead of the value or something, but clearly I don't know batch very well at all so I could be way off.

Comment: I have written a lot of batch in my life and never once tried an array!  I'd be surprised that a variable within a variable works.  But I can't discount the possibility.  Is there a reason you have to use batch?  If you are learning something new, why not focus on something more modern?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running this on?

Comment: @uSlackr there is a reason, it's a bit weird to explain but basically the framework my application is running on does really weird things with modifying standard input/output locations and intentionally makes it really difficult to override that, so the best way I've come up with to provide the user with usage info and input verification info is to wrap the executable in a batch script that process the arguments they pass in and prints and syntax error explanations and help info.

Comment: @uSlackr Windows 10

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71353845/batch-expand-nested-variable-without-delayed-expansion

Comment: @uSlackr I followed that link and it didn't quite get me to where I wanted but it got me to another link that did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891120/batch-for-loop-next-item-in-list

I was able to adapt the second option in the top answer to change my array processing to get what I wanted. I'll update the original post with my solution.

Comment: @batchconfusesme Which framework is that?

Comment: @Gantendo Unity

Comment: [Please do not put "solved" in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/355310); and do not put your solution in the question, post a proper answer below. I have removed your solution from the question but you can still find it in the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1807622/revisions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your current script is that `!args[!nextIndex!]!` gets evaluated like `!args[!, "nextIndex", !]!`. Batch doesn't have another way to indicate delayed variables or to do addition inside a variable name, so your best bet for argument pairs is to create a second, offset array like `argsNext` does below. I've adjusted `argsLength` to be 0-based as well:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set i=0
:TOP
IF (%1) == () GOTO END
    set args[!i!]=%1
    set argsNext[!i!]=%2
    set /A i+=1
SHIFT
GOTO TOP
:END

set /A i=%i%-1
set argsLength=!i!
echo argsLength: !argsLength!
for /l %%n in (0,1,!argsLength!) do ( 
    set /A nextIndex = %%n + 1
    echo n: %%n, arg: !args[%%n]!, nextIndex: !nextIndex!, nextIndexArg: !argsNext[%%n]!
)
```

Output looks like:

```
c:\test>test.bat a b c
argsLength: 2
n: 0, arg: a, nextIndex: 1, nextIndexArg: b
n: 1, arg: b, nextIndex: 2, nextIndexArg: c
n: 2, arg: c, nextIndex: 3, nextIndexArg:
```

Comment: there's no need to duplicate the array at an offset. a simple for loop can be used to expand the calculated offset value instead.

Comment: @T3RROR What you're describing sounds to me like the solution I ended up coming across, but Cpt.Whale's answer works as well so I marked it as accepted